# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check in signalR

Tags: angular, cors, signalr.client, asp.net-core-2.2, signalr-2

The application has been working flawlessly in .net core 2.1. The signalR server's configuration looks like the following code snippet in `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method:

```

```
services.AddCors(setupAction =>
  setupAction.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()))
```

```

And in Configuration method I have the following code snippet:

```

```
 app.UseCors("MyPolicy")
```

```

The angular client app's code starts the connection like the following code snippet:

```

```
this._connection = this._connection || new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('https://localhost:44314/xyz/test?abc=123', options)
        .build();
```

```

As I said, this setup has always been working fine. I upgraded the .net core application (signalR server) from 2.1 to 2.2 (dotnetcore SDK ver 2.2.101) and I upgraded the signalR client package to 1.1.0. The signalR server serves an angular app and another C# application. The C# application connects to the signalR server perfectly and it does whatever it's supposed to do but the angular app produces the following error message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://localhost:44314/xyz/test/negotiate?abc=123' from origin
>   'https://localhost:44303' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

The signalR client's version is 1.1.0 in both angular app and the C# client application.

Any reasons why such an upgrade to .net core 2.2 causes this communication failure and what the possible solution is?!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, browser expalins clearly what is wrong. You cannot use `allowAnyOrigin` (thats `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in response with `allowCredentials`). Either narrow down the origin access or  remove credentials allowance.

I am not sure if the credentials part is caused because of rule to accept credential headers or because credentials are actually present in the request. You will have to check that out.

> Any reasons why such an upgrade to .net core 2.2 causes this communication failure

Maybe implementation did change in that manner in a way that internally mentioned options were mutually exclusive while now full control is given back to the programmer - but that is only a lucky guess.

Comment: I removed credentials allowance but that did not help.

Comment: Is client sending the credentials ? If so, it wont pass with wildcarded origin. You would have to compare OPTIONS response with those you had before upgrade to see what did actually change as you indirectly states that FE app didnt change.

Comment: Mozilla says clearly - You shall not pass!! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions for this problem that can one pick either of them:

Solution 1: Either specify the CORS origin explicitly.
Solution 2: Or write a middleware to produce the expected headers.

Further info found here:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4457